# Returning an object from fetch API with async await

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm having trouble returning an object from a fetch request.

When I log this to console, it says the promise is pending but [[PromiseResult]] in Dev Tools shows the object correctly.

What would be the most effective way to return this?

```
async function() {

    const response = await fetch(`url`);

    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    if (!jsonResponse) {
        return [];
    }
    return jsonResponse; 
}
```

Comment: Well… are you `await`ing *this* function when calling it?

Comment: Yes, even if I await the function call it still responds the same.

Comment: You are awaiting *this* function (it doesn't have a name, so I don't know how I should refer to it…)?! `const obj = await function()` (where `function` is this `async function` from your question)?